# Merging two objects to make a corner

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm making a hill/elevated surface, and I wanted to add in self-intersection corners, which would allow for me to have corner peices. I already tried to make both walls objects, and boolean them, but only one of the walls booleaned correctly, and the behavior could not be replicated on the other wall (even if I duplicated step 1 and tried to target the opposite wall). Here are two pictures:

This is a picture showing two walls overlapping.
[image]

This is a crude drawing showing in red, what triangles I want to be omitted, while the other faces are seamlessly merged together, thus creating a corner.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was evidently to choose "union". Visually, it doesn't delete the other unwanted faces, but if you apply the boolean modifier, it will allow you to select the unwanted faces afterwards and delete them.

[image]

[image]